# Add tsconfig.json properties to Gulp task

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp

I keep on getting that error about using something different than ES5 standards while compiling, simply because I just started using TS and I don't know how to include the `tsconfig.json` directly in my Gulp task autocompile.

**`error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher`**

### Is it possible to add my `tsconfig.json` file properties directly into my Gulp pipe?

Current `gulpfile.js`

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json'); // TypeScript config
var merge = require('merge2'); // TypeScript requirement
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var del = require('del');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/assets/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass()) // Using gulp-sass
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('typescript', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src('app/assets/typescript/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            declaration: true
        }));

    return merge([
        tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/definitions')),
        tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'))
    ]);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch('app/assets/typescript/**/*.ts', ['typescript']);
    gulp.watch('app/assets/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/assets/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
    });
});

gulp.task('useref', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/assets/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
        // Caching images that ran through imagemin
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({
            interlaced: true
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/img'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/assets/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', function () {
    return del.sync('dist');
});

gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
    runSequence('clean:dist', ['sass', 'useref', 'images', 'fonts'],
        callback
    );
});

gulp.task('default', function (callback) {
    runSequence(['sass', 'typescript', 'browserSync', 'watch'],
        callback
    );
    // Typescript compiler
});
```

Comment: See this part of the readme: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript#using-tsconfigjson

Comment: @Paarth, I did that multiple times, but it seems I did a mistake with the piping intself. I removed the default `.pipe(ts({ declaration: true }))` and replaced it with the `.pipe(tsProject());` and it seems to be working fine now. Is this going to be an issue without that "declaration:true" setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use your tsconfig.json as the only source of the properties. To do this change how you create `tsResult`:

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

var tsResult = tsProject.src().
    .pipe(//....
```

Below is the complete task that works for me:

```
gulp.task('build.js.dev', () => 
{
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())   
        .pipe(tsProject()); 

    return merge([
        //Write definitions 
        //tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest(TEMP_TARGET_FOLDER)),
        //Write compiled js
        tsResult.js.pipe(sourcemaps.write(
            ".", 
            { 
                includeContent: true, 
                sourceRoot: __dirname + "/dist"
            })).pipe(gulp.dest(TEMP_TARGET_FOLDER))]);
});
```

The error you are getting is due to the fact that if you omit `target` compiler option the typescript compiler will fallback to ES3.

Comment: I applied `.pipe(tsProject());` and it seems to fix the issue. Is this a problem regarding the usage of the previous `.pipe(ts({ declaration: true }))`

Comment: This is due to the fact that by default typescript compiler targets ES3, see here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: So basically the `.pipe(ts({ declaration: true }))` means that it works with ES3 ?

Comment: Yes. As you have not specified any other options - it will use their default values

Comment: Thanks! A much needed clarification for a beginner.